Efficiently calculate an availability date from a list of project assignments and known capacity
I'm looking for an efficient way to calculate the date each member of a team is available given a set of project assignments. There are 25 team members, each with a set of capacities and assignments.
Capacities are a percentage availability between two dates (this is how part-time hours are supported, 100% being full-time), with null end dates for scenarios where the capacity is indefinite. Capacities can be zero, to support things such as secondments or parental leave.
Assignments link a team member to a project for a percentage between two dates. This allows a member to have two projects at the same time (say a 60/40 split) and these add up to the capacity of the team member. So if a person has 60% capacity, they might have two projects 30% each.
All of this works perfectly, but now I want to calculate the date each person in the team is available next. I can do this in what feels like a brute-force way by using a loop to count forward one day at a time until I arrive at a point where the total assigned percentage is less than the capacity, but this feels wildly inefficient - is there a better way?
I've added a Gantt chart image to show what I mean, I'd like to calculate the dates where the red lines are. Any help, even pseudo-code, is greatly appreciated. The application stack is NodeJS and Vue, and I'm using the Luxon library in the brute-force method. Language doesn't matter, I'm looking for help with the general approach to the problem that I can then implement in JS.


I think the “brute force method” is ok, I don't think it would slow down the program much. The only better solution I have come up with is to create a hash map and update the date for each employee when their schedule changes.

@RobG StackOverflow is not only for asking about concrete code. As long as the requirements are clearly stated, there exists an optimal algorithm to compute the result. This is very much on-topic.


I can do this in what feels like a brute-force way by using a loop to count forward one day at a time until I arrive at a point where the total assigned percentage is less than the capacity, but this feels wildly inefficient - is there a better way?

There's no need to do that one day at a time. If you have the capacities and assignments of the team member, all you need to do is look at the dates on which the percentages change - not at each day until you find a solution (which might be never if they have an indefinite 0% capacity).
Sort the events by date, then process them in order, until you reach either the end of the events or find a date where capacity will exceed assignments. Since you may need only a few events until that point, you don't even have to sort the entire list of events, but can do it lazily, e.g. with a min heap.

This is perfect, it didn't even cross my mind to look at just a handful of key dates.
